# What alkali and alkaline earth metal oxides will turn moist red litmus blue and finally white?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, ph

> How many of the following will turn moist red litmus blue and finally white?
>
> $\ce{Li2O}$, $\ce{KO3}$, $\ce{RbO2}$, $\ce{Cs2O2}$, $\ce{BeO}$, $\ce{MgO}$, $\ce{BaO2}$, $\ce{SrO}$.

Since bleach convert moist red litmus blue and then white, but how we can identify which compound will act as bleach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard oxides $\ce{Li2O, MgO}$ and $\ce{SrO}$ are water soluble and hydrolyse to form hydroxides and a basic solution. $\ce{BeO}$ is insoluble in water.

$\ce{RbO2}$ is a superoxide which in aqueous solution undergoes disproportionation to $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ so will give a blue litmus test.

The peroxides $\ce{Cs2O2}$ and $\ce{BaO2}$ react with water to give hydrogen peroxide and the hydroxides, so again a basic solution[(source)](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/1_s-Block_Elements/Group__1%3A_The_Alkali_Metals/2Reactions_of_the_Group_1_Elements/Reactions_of_Group_I_Elements_with_Oxygen). The hydrogen peroxide produced will bleach the litmus paper.

$\ce{KO3}$(Potassium Ozonide) is highly unstable, [decomposes in water to $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{KOH}$](http://www.allreactions.com/index.php/group-1a/potassium-k/potassium-ozonide-ko3)

The oxides which will NOT decolorize litmus are $\ce{Li2O, MgO, BeO}$ and $\ce{SrO}$. The peroxides ($\ce{Cs2O2}$ and $\ce{BaO2}$), the superoxide($\ce{RbO2}$) and the ozonide($\ce{KO3}$) will decolorize litmus.

Comment: KO3 is Potassium Ozonide

Comment: RbO2 is technically a superoxide.

Comment: @OscarLanzi quite correct, my error. I will correct the entry

Comment: @Waylander Can you mention Compound Name clearly which finally turn white ? I am asking this because in my book answer of this question is given as 4 I.e. 4 Compound will turn white finally. A/c to your answer only 3 compound will turn white.